# Change Connection details From a Azure Analysis Server to a Azure SQL Server during deployment of the Model

Tags: sql-server, azure-analysis-services

In our situation we have a Analysis Model connected to an Azure SQL Server
The connection of this model is dynamically updated during the deployment of this model (same  base model other data sources.

In the previous situation the model connected to the sql server based on usercode/password which are stored in the model.

This is executed in code like:

```
   <# .asdatabase #>
   $filename = $sourcePath + '/' + $asFileName +  '.asdatabase'
   $json = Get-Content -Path $filename -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json
   $json.name = $asModelName
   $dataSource = $json.model.dataSources[0]
   $dataSource.connectionDetails.address.server = $dbServerFullName
   $dataSource.connectionDetails.address.database = $dbName
   $dataSource.credential.Username = $dbUserName
   Write-Json $filename $json
```

Now I like to connect to the databse based on a managed identity.
How must I prefill the connection details, if it is even possible.

Regards,
Bart